# Probablity density function $f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v},t)$

Tags: lattice-model, phase-space

The phase density function is usually denoted as [$f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v},t)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_equation) which gives probable number of particles moving with velocity $ \mathbf{v}$ at position $\mathbf{x}$ at time t. Also we assume that position and velocities of particles are not correlated i.e. $\mathbf{x} $ and $\mathbf{v}$ are independent.

We use  $f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v},t)$ as a basis  Lattice Boltzmann functionto solve fluid dynamics equations.
$$ f_i(\mathbf {x} +\Delta \mathbf {x},  t + \Delta  t) - f_i(\mathbf {x}, t ) =  -\frac{\Delta t}{\tau} (f_i - f^{eq}_i)
$$

The entire point of solving fluid dynamics equation is(If I am correct) to know velocity at a given point and time. How can we use  $f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v},t)$ to proceed with lattice Boltzmann equation when  $f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v},t)$ has multiple values of velocities at given point $\mathbf{x}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

At a given point in space, there are several values of $f_i$, one for each discrete velocity $v_i$. So you have to apply the lattice-Boltzmann equation as many times. This is exactly the point of the lattice-Boltzmann method: each "element" is actually defined by its discrete value of the velocity. You apply the equation for each of these elements which have a given, fixed velocity.